# Retrieve image and .txt file from parse.com and display in an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, parse-platform

I have a listview with a list of appetizers. Once I click on a row item, a single activity will display the name of the recipe, the cook time, the image and a text file converted to string into a textview.  I am able to display the name and cook time through an intent, but unable to display the image and text from the text file on parse.

This code goes through the list and displays the last in the list.  This is not what I want:

```
final ParseImageView mImage = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> getimage = new ParseQuery<>("Appetizers");
            getimage.addAscendingOrder("appetizer");
            getimage.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // success
                        for (ParseObject parseObject : objects) {
                            ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) parseObject.get("imageFiles");

                        Log.d("test", "Get your image..." + fileObject.getUrl());
                        Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(fileObject.getUrl()).placeholder
                                (R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(mImage);
                    }
                } else {
                    // fail
                    Log.d("test", "Error Message..." + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

**Images:**

parse.com "Appetizers" class:

[image: parse.com "Appetizers" class]

List of recipes:

[image: List of recipes]

AppetizerRecipe layout XML:

[image: AppetizerRecipe layout XML]

Log:

[image: Log]

Out of layout:

[image: Out of layout]

Answer (score 0):

Did you get something in the log "test" where you print the url? I mean this line:

```
Log.d("test", "Get your image..." + fileObject.getUrl());
```

If so, the problem is not the Parse Server. Instead, check if Picasso is working well.

Please update the question with the code where you read the file.

Comment: yes, i am getting the address and the pic, but i am getting the last pic of the class, which is not the one i picked.

Comment: Yes, because the ImageView is loaded with the last iteration of your foreach. On your parse query you have to put the item id you want retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

According the comments for my original response, you have to do something like this.

In your ListViewItem's Listener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int id = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).id;
            Intent descriptionActivity = new Intent(this, DescActivity.class);
            descriptionActivity.putExtra("id",id);
            startActivity(descriptionActivity);
        }
```

In your DescActivity's `onCreate()` method:

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

and finally in your ParseQuery:

`getImage.where('objectId',id);`

I hope this help.

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested, but it is still doing the exact same thing.  All i want to do is to be able to get the image from parse.com and place it in the image view. The code ... getImage.where ... there are many instances of where, any particular one i should use?

Comment: try: query.whereEqualTo("id", id);

Comment: i figured it out.  I added my answer but it would;t let me accept my own answer, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

By adding logging messages as to what was being passed and what not, i was able to fix the problem.  Hope this helps someone else.

In the sending class:

```
ParseObject po = mAppetizers.get(position); // get position
String ID = po.getObjectId().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(Appetizer.this, AppetizerRecipe.class);

intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the receiver's class:

```
final ParseImageView mImage = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
String ID = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> getimage = new ParseQuery<>("Appetizers");
    getimage.addAscendingOrder("appetizer");
    getimage.whereEqualTo("ID", ID);
        Log.d("AppetizerRecipe2", "object: " + ID);
    getimage.getInBackground(ID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.v("what is e?", "e = " + e);
                // success
                final ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile)object.get("imageFiles");
                fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d("test", "We've got data in data.");
                            // use data for something
                            Log.d("test", "Get your image..." + fileObject.getUrl());
                    Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(fileObject.getUrl()).placeholder
                            (R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(mImage);

                        } else {
                            Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // fail
                Log.d("test", "Error Message..." + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```